# Saving Streamed Audio from Mic on Adobe FMS

Tags: actionscript, streaming, flash-media-server

Im trying to capture mic data from a swf, stream it to adobe flash media server, and save it as a wav file.  Currently I can only stream the mic data to the server and save it in FLV format.  Anyone know how I can covert it to a WAV or save it as a WAV?

Answer (score 1):

FMS can only create FLVs, however I'm fairly sure you can use ffmpeg to convert the FLV to WAV. You could have FMS call out to some other script on the server that would trigger ffmpeg to do the conversion.

Comment: Why do you say FMS can only create FLVs, any reference?

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of FMS, it has the ability to write MP4 and I believe F4V as well. I suggest that you stream to FLV and use FFmpeg to convert to WAV as a post process.